# Final size in Illustrator CS4 masked images

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask, cs4

How do I find out the exact size of a graphic or image after it has a clipping mask applied in Illustrator? When you just select the image or do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> it shows the entire image size(including the masked unwanted portion) in the transform palette and I just need the final dimensions of the image. Can anyone suggest how I can find out what the masked image size is?

Comment: See also http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21513/how-to-get-an-illustrator-script-to-see-the-visible-size-of-clipped-art-instead. Maybe that helps.

Comment: You should post what version of Illustrator you are using, because more recent versions don't show the clipped content.

Comment: Sorry, I am using Adobe Illustrator CS4.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to layers, open a masked group and alt-click on the layer with mask contour. It will select the mask and show the size. I think it should work in cs4 too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older version of Illustrator, you'll need to not simply "Select All", or select all, then de-select the masked content and use the **Direct Selection Tool** (White arrow) - or Layers Panel -  to select only the clipping mask shape rather than the entire clipped group.

The inclusion of non-visible clipped content was an annoyance many users complained about, which is why more recent versions of Illustrator no longer show content which is not visible.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I can understand using the Direct Selection Tool to find size of the masked content. But I get graphics, advertisements in vector and there will be multiple of empty boxes or color outlines in addition to the masked content and it will have more number of paths too.. If I am able to find out only the final masked size that will be great.

Comment: There's no way, in previous versions, to simply disable the display of non-visible clipped content. You can draw a rectangle around the area you wish to measure and measure the rectangle. That's about your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Logesh,
Double click on the masked image it goes into the mask then you can select the image it will show the original size. Or you select the masked image and right click-->Release clipping mask then you can show the original size.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. In addition, realize the user is using Illustrator CS4.

Comment: I hope that second option can apply in CS4.

Answer (score -1):

TLDR Answer: Use an artboard and put it around that clipping mask, whatever measurement your artboard is will be your end result.

Save, Cash out, Bro down!